# Java lastIndexOf always return -1 if the character is space and fromIndex is set

Tags: java, string, lastindexof

**Test Code**

```
public class HelloWorld{
     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World".lastIndexOf(' '));
        System.out.println("Hello World".lastIndexOf(' ', 1));
        System.out.println("Hello World".lastIndexOf('e'));
        System.out.println("Hello World".lastIndexOf('e', 1));
     }
}
```

**Result**

```
5
-1
1
1
```

I expected the second result be 5 but it is -1. How can the first one is right but the second is wrong?

Comment: Checkout Documentation :                                                                                 @return  the index of the last occurrence of the character in the
     *          character sequence represented by this object that is less
     *          than or equal to {@code fromIndex}, or {@code -1}
     *          if the character does not occur before that point.

Comment: From the javadoc : " if no such character occurs in this string _at or before_ position _fromIndex_, then -1 is returned." .

Comment: Thx guys. I know  -1 is not found but I didn't notice if right to left. The variable named fromIndex confused me and I assume it search the substring of start from fromIndex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lastIndexOf()` goes from right to left, so when it starts with index 1 (the second character, namely 'e'), it does not find a space (which has index 5).

Answer (score 2):

**Simplest Way**

> lastIndexOf(int ch, int fromIndex) returns index of ch only if it occurs at or before fromIndex, Otherwise return -1.

```
System.out.println("Hello World".lastIndexOf(' ', 3));
```

> returns -1.

```
System.out.println("He llo World".lastIndexOf(' ', 3));
```

> returns 2.